# Subgraph indexed network is missing from manifest

Tags: testnets, zkevm

i tried to deploy many times and got this errors messages.

✖️ Failed to deploy to Graph node https://api.thegraph.com/deploy/: subgraph failure::Subgraph indexed network is missing from manifest[image]

Answer (score 1):

This means that this network is not supported on hosted-service. Check this page for the lis of supported networks: https://thegraph.com/docs/en/developing/supported-networks/